# Button click makes a div popup and after 5 seconds it closes itselfs

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, setinterval

I'm trying to create a div that contains CSS style as a popup that closes itself after 5 seconds. 
I'd appreciate any help because I don't know what to do, that what I have so far, but it not working.

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
#divPopUp {
    border: 2px black solid;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<script>
function popUpFunc() {
    ref = setInterval(function () {
            var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=200,height=100");
            myWindow.document.write('divPopUp'.style);
        }, 10000
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        myWindow.clearInterval(ref);
    }, 5000)
}
</script>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="popup" onclick="popUpFunc()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For applying css property use inline css:
Every 5 sec open the new window show the content then it will close itself.

Try this code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>
function popUpFunc() {

    setInterval(function () {
       var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=200,height=100");
       myWindow.document.write("<div style=' border: 2px black solid;background-color: blue;width: 200px;height: 200px;'>This is MsgWindow</div>")
        setTimeout(function(){
         myWindow.close();
        },1000)

    }, 5000)
}
</script>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="popup" onclick="popUpFunc()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:
Every 5 sec pop up will open and close itself

```
<head>
    <style>
#divPopUp {
    border: 2px black solid;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
    </style>
</head>
<script>
function popUpFunc() {

    setInterval(function () {
       var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=200,height=100");
       myWindow.close();
    }, 5000)
}
</script>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="popup" onclick="popUpFunc()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

but I want to go up window to show style #divPopUp as I were using a <div id=divPopUp></div> and then closes the window after 5 seconds.

Comment: added answer another post.try it.

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid `document.write`. Use `createElement` instead

```
function popUpFunc(){
    var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=200,height=100");

    /* Get <head>-Element from Popup */
    var popupHead = myWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    /* Create Text-Node */
    var popupCss = document.createTextNode('#divPopUp {\
    border: 2px black solid;\
    background-color: blue;\
    width: 200px;\
    height: 200px;\
}');
    /* Create style-Element */
    var popupStyle = document.createElement('style');    
    /* Adding Text-Node to style-Element */
    popupStyle.appendChild(popupCss);
    /* Append style-element to Popup-<head> */
    popupHead.appendChild(popupStyle);

    /* Get <body>-Element from Popup */
    var popupBody = myWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    /* Create div-Element */
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', 'divPopUp');
    /* Append DIV to body */
    popupBody.appendChild(div);

    /* Close Popup after 5 seconds*/
    setTimeout( function(){ myWindow.close() }, 5000);
};
```

DEMO: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/S5AUD/